# Partition-Algebra-Correspondence

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have a question on a statement in Pliska, Introduction to Mathematical Finance (Blackwell, 1997), p. 75. The author defines an algebra of sets on the space $\Omega$ in the usual way and then claims:

"Given an algebra on $\Omega$, denoted $\mathscr{F}_t$, you can always find a unique collection $\{F_n\}$ of subsets $F_n$ such that
(a) each $F_n \in \mathscr{F}_t$,
(b) the subsets $\{F_n\}$ are disjoint, and 
(c) the union of the subsets $\{F_n\}$ equals $\Omega$."

I am somewhat irritated. Firstly, as to the notation: what is meant by the difference of $F_n$ and $\{F_n\}$? I mean, if we take (c) in the sence of single-element-sets, then their union will be a system of sets. How can this equal $\Omega$?
Secondly, if I just ignore this notation, why not simply always take $F_1 = \Omega$ and I'm good?! What about uniqueness then?

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

He is claiming there is an unique, pairwise disjoint, collection C that is a subset of $\mathscr{F}_t$ with $\cup C = \Omega.$

I agree his notation is lacking in quality.
Instead of pairwise disjoint, could he mean $\cap$C is empty?
That C is collectively disjoint?

As (c) is a requirement, there is no counterexample.

You have pointed out, one possibility for C is { $\Omega$ }.
Thus the puzzle, how can C be unique without additional requirements?
Interpreting (b) to be $\cap$C is empty, ruins your example for C.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I see how the first idea (i.e. assuming $\bigcap C = \emptyset$) makes sense. But still, this would always give us the possibilty $C = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it does.   Have you considered using a real  math book?

Comment: Haha, I'm rather annoyed with my professor for copying that verbatim. I guess what is meant is more like a "minimal generating set" (with some extra conditions). Anyway, thanks for your help - at least I'm positive that I'm not simply missing something here...